# Moved a Magento site from one server to another. HTTPS:// redirects to old server

Tags: magento

I moved a Magento site from one server to another.  In the settings, I updated the base url and secure base url.  Http:// works just find.  Https:// redirects back to the old server.

I'm not sure where to look or what information to post. How do I fix this?

Edit:

I had made sure the base urls were correct on the GLOBAL settings.  I didn't think to go down to the website and store levels.  The developer before me had changed it for the store, since his dev server didn't have SSL set up.  Sigh...

All's good now.  Thanks Alan!

Comment: Are you using a managed hosting solution? How did you manage generating the SSL certs the first time?

Comment: The new server had an existing Magneto installation.  I overwrote all of the Magento files with the new files.  It is a shared hosting server.  I didn't create the SSL certs.  I was brought in after just to move everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one of many different things, including Magento configuration or Apache configuration.

On the Magento side, check the `core_config_data` table -- specifically where the `path` value is `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`.  These fields are how Magento identifies the base site URL, and will use the secure version to redirect users back to the older site.

Also, after changing these values in `core_config_data`, you'll need to clear you Magento cache (in `var/cache`) to force a reload.

**Update**: Don't forget to check for values set at a different store/website level.

Comment: I updated the base urls and cleared the cache. No luck.  Oddly:  https://<url>  redirects to the old server,  but https://<ur>/admin goes to the admin page of the new server, not the old dev server.

Comment: Also:  use on frontend and use in admin are both set to "yes"

Comment: If that's true it sounds like an apache issue or a custom code in magento issue.  One last tip -- use curl with the `-i/-I` flags to get an idea what sort of redirect is being generated.  Good luck.

Comment: I didn't think to check the website or store levels for base_url changes.  The dev before me modified the store level secure base url.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  For future people, it's always best to check the data in `core_config_data` directly to immediately reveal any store level configuration items.

Comment: What's interesting is nowhere in the database did it mention the old URL.  I dumped the entire DB and searched through it in a text editor.  I have no idea why it didn't show up in there.